# Is it posible to use wp.data.select('core') outside a block?

Tags: rest-api, block-editor

I have an options page I have created for a post type which doesn't use a Guttenberg block, but I was wondering if inside that page I could somehow make use `@wordpress/data` in order to retrieve posts with the below instead of using the REST API?

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post' )
```

Right now, `wp.data.select('core')` simply returns `null`

Comment: `getEntityRecords` uses the REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sorry**, you can not use it outside of Guttenberg block.
**but you can get same result every where in wp-admin by using the following solution**,

For Detail visit the [WP Official Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/)

```
this.posts = {};
this.posts = new wp.api.models.Post();
this.posts.fetch().then( response => {
   console.log(response);
});
```

The following is an example how i have used it on my pluging custom testing page which was developed on gutenberg components.

```
  import {render,Component} from "@wordpress/element";

    class TestingPage extends Component {
            constructor() {
                super( ...arguments );

                // Solution - Start 
                this.posts = {};
                this.posts = new wp.api.models.Post();
                this.posts.fetch().then( response => {
                   console.log(response);
                });
                // Solution - End

        }

        render(
            <TestingPage/>,
            document.getElementById( 'testing-page' )
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this alternative, Ejaz. I still wonder what are the limitations which would prevent the data module to access post data outside a Guttenberg block. However, I believe your suggestion is a nice utility method to use as a fallback, alternatively to @wordpress/api-fetch.

Comment: Always Welcome  @zanona